# pubnub test application crashes: NoClassDefFound

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, pubnub

this is a copy of my question on Pubnub support page:

Hi all, I tried running the PubnubTestApp that is downloadable with the Pubnub API from your git repo.

but when I try and start the test app i firstly get a build path error because apparently you (pubnub guys) have configured the project to look for 2 jar files that don't exist. (bcprov-jdk16-145.jar and commons-codec-1.2.jar).

after I removed those 2 references the project showed no error. but when I tried running it, it crashed again with this error:

```
"07-04 12:29:11.782: E/AndroidRuntime(754): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.fbt/com.fbt.PubNubTestActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fbt.PubNubTestActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.fbt-1.apk"
```

after looking over the internet for the reasons for this crash, I noticed that in the manifest.xml file in the project there is a mistake in the name of the activity name. (it's named ".PubNubTestActivity" instead of ".PubnubTestActivity").

after changing the manifest, everything works and the app will install and run but there a a few problems still.

when pressing the "publish" button or the "history" button the app crashes and dies automatically. also it crashed without any clicking of anything (just like that).

here are the crash reports I got from the emulator.

http://pastie.org/private/pojnpnxmznvn9azdg7uyg

apparently the project doesn't recognize the "pubnub.crypto" jar file even though I (and you) added it to the build path and made sure it's in the project.

please let me know how to fix this so I can use (at last) pubnub in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the latest build? This should be fixed now.